# How to perform nested navigation in visionOS

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationsplitview, visionos

I'm displaying a simple `NavigationStack` with some options, which navigate to a component with a `NavigationView` that looks something like this:

```
NavigationView {
    List(courseMetadata.lessons, selection: $selection) { lesson in
        NavigationLink {
            LessonDetail(lesson: lesson)
        } label: {
            LessonRow(lesson: lesson)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Main title")
}
.navigationTitle(course.fullTitle)
```

my problem is that the inner `NavigationLinks` seems to be pushing `LessonDetail` on the top `NavigationStack` instead of the `NavigationView`, losing the left menu as in the expected result below.-

[image]

I actually managed to get this result by replacing `NavigationView` for a `NavigationSplitView`, like this.-

```
NavigationSplitView {
    List(courseMetadata.lessons, selection: $selection) { lesson in
        NavigationLink(value: lesson) {
            LessonRow(lesson: lesson)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("\(courseMetadata.lessons.count) Lessons")
} detail : {
    if let lesson = selection {
        LessonDetail(lesson: lesson)
    }
}
.navigationTitle("Main title")
```

which might be good enough, but unfortunately I'm losing the nice styles the system sets for NavigationView.-

[image]

So, my question is, **is there any way to specify in which NavigationView I want to stack my detail view?**

**EDIT**
Alternatively, if there's any "straightforward" way to setup `NavigationSplitView` so that it looks like NavigationView (nice container background, horizontal dividers and chevron icons), that'd do the trick too :)

Comment: NavigationView was deprecated quite a few versions ago. You should use Navigation Split View I wouldn’t expect vision to work with  NavigatinView

Comment: Thank you @loremipsum. Mm sorry to hear that, it's funny because `NavigationView` does actually looks nicer to me in the screenshots :(

Comment: Try changing your list style to “plain”

Comment: Actually `.grouped` style did the trick! Thank you @loremipsum, please feel free to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NavigationView
```

Was deprecated a few OS versions ago, I wouldn’t expect vision OS to work with it.

Alternatively you can use

```
NavigationSplitView
```

With

```
.listStyle(.grouped)
```